# Find specific elements in group $U_{60}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

We have group $U_{60} = \left \{ w, w^{2},w^{3},...,w^{60}=1 \right \}$. An element $a \in U_{60}$ is called “Good” element if the equation $a^{x}=b$ has solution for exactly $16$ values of $ b\in U_{60}$. Find the number of “Good” elements.

I really don’t know what to do. I know that the order of an element divides the order of the group, so the elements’ order can be $\left \{1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30 \right \}$ I know that $ord(w^{k}) = \frac{60}{gcd(60,k)} $but I can’t understand how to build the solution. Any clues?

Comment: If $a$ is a good element, then the cyclic group $\operatorname{gr}(a)$ generated by $a$ has $16$ elements. Next, the Lagrange theorem works.

Comment: @kabenyuk but how can this cyclic subgroup have 16 elements? The order of a subgroup should divide the order of the group. And 16 does not divide 60.

Comment: @kabenyuk or is that the answer? Due to Lagrange’s theorem there are no good elements……

Comment: Yes,  there are no good elements!

Comment: @kabenyuk thanks a lot!